How do I avoid extra "block sender" questions when marking messages as spam?
I use keyboard shortcuts to mark messages as spam in Gmail, so it is fast and painless: mark with x, kill with !, no problems.
Alas, nowadays Gmail asks stupid questions like "do you also want to unsubscribe?" and/or "do you also want to block the sender?" - and my answer is always invariably NO.
Is there a way to disable these "features"?
PS. The reasons I find these questions annoyingly stupid is that

they interfere with my keyboard-based workflow and
they defeat the purpose of ML-based spam filtering by introducing a hard-coded "sender block" and
they propose that I communicate back with the spammers.

